# Iterating through an array of strings, and removing parts of their values in Bash?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, bash

How to iterate through an array of strings, and remove parts of their values? (BASH)

I have an array populated with a list of sites saved as strings, and I want to grab the sections of them that are to the left of '.com.au' and save them to a new array. There are also a couple of items in the string that don't end with '.com.au' and I want to ignore them completely.

To make it a bit easier to read, I've removed most of the code and only left in what I think will be relevant to the question:

```
#!/bin/bash
full_array(*); declare -p full_array
edited_array=()

for x in ${full_array[@]};
    #If x ends with '.com.au'
        #Remove '.com.au' from x
        #Save output to edited_array
    #Else
        #Skip item
done
```

Will I have to use regex to do this? If so, does anyone know of any good tutorials online that would be worth checking out?

Comment: is there a special reason you have to do it with bash? have you tried sed or awk?

Comment: I've been told to write it in bash, so I'm trying to stick to that.

Comment: You want to use `"${full_array[@]}"` (the quotes are important) to make sure you handle files/entries/etc. with spaces and shell metacharacters correctly. You don't need regex (though you could use them) you could also just use [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to try to strip the suffix and compare the stripped value to the original value.

Comment: There's a `do` missing after the `for x in ...;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
for x in ${full_array[@]};do
[[ $x == *.com.au ]] && edited_array+=("${x%.com.au}")
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $x == *.com.au ]]; then
    edited_array+=( "${x%.com.au}" )
fi
```

Inside bash double brackets, the `==` operator is a pattern-matching operator. Then, just use shell parameter expansion to remove the domain and append to the array with `+=`

Comment: I edited my code to include that (literally just copying/pasting it in the for loop), but now I'm getting an unexpected EOF error telling me it's looking for a closing quote. Do you know what might be going on? I can't see any open quotes anywhere?

Comment: I did a correction but it's still not visible. You should replace the '#' by a '%'.

Comment: My previous comment was about the answer. Now about the first comment and the missing quotes: there's a "do" keyword missing after the "for x in ..." line in the snippet of your question. Type `help for` in your terminal and you'll see.

Comment: I tried that but I'm getting the same error? :(

Here's what I have if it makes it helps:
http://pastebin.com/AKVD7dG6

Edit: Oh and getting rid of the last line doesn't work either.

Comment: @Thorium, naitoon was right: change the `#.com.au` to `%.com.au` to remove it from the end of the string.